# How does the WMD editor like the one StackOverFlow uses work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, markdown

I'm interested in knowing how does the text you type on the text box doesn't require a page refresh? 
Some similar alternatives include:

[lixlpixel](http://fundisom.com/live_preview.html)

But they tend to do a page refresh every time a keystroke is pressed...

Comment: oooh, a new acronym! Weapon Of Mass Destruction?

Comment: @spender Web Mark Down would be my guess

Comment: That's all cleared up then. Thanks.

Comment: @spender Sometimes it feels like that :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have a Markdown to HTML translator implemented in Javascript. Whenever the content of the 'textarea' changes the preview area is updated with the result of running the Markdown to HTML converter. There's obviously more to it than that -- making this sort of thing perform well can be tricky -- but that's the essence of it.

If you inspect the textarea in a browser like Safari you can see that they are using Javascript event handlers for drop, input, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown and paste events. When one of these events happen the script responds appropriately, including to run the Javacript Markdown-to-HTML converter and putting the resulting HTML into the preview area.

Comment: not quite my question. I specifically asked how is the content of the text area transfered to the preview area without a page refresh...

Comment: > Whenever the content of the 'textarea' changes the preview area is updated

Comment: still not answering my question? its like how does a car start up? you turn the car key. Well it does but you omitted the, when you turn the key, small amounts of fuel is sprayed into the ignition chamber, in the mean while the car generator charges up enough to create a spark that would light up the fuel, this process continues until the cycle loops. Just saying when ever the content changes and the prview area is update is not telling me anything new. I have clearly stated that lixlpixel exists, but it refreshes the page every key stroke, WMD doesnt HOW?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not going to waste any more time on this question. If explaining that it uses event handlers to, upon each change to the text area, convert the markdown into HTML and then put that into the preview area isn't enough detail you'll need to look at the code. Or wait for another answer.